# Add separate legend in ggplot for trendline

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a line plot with a trend-line in `ggplot2` with `geom_line`, `geom_point` and `geom_smooth`. My code is similar to this.

```
year <- as.character(2011:2020)
x <- c(12, 13, 12.5, 14, 15, 17, 16, 18, 18, 19)
y <- c(25, 28, 30, 27, 30, 31, 30, 31, 33, 33)

dat <- data.frame(year, x, y) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(x,y), names_to = "item", values_to = "price")

ggplot(dat,  aes(x=year, y=price, group=item, col=item))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(shape=item))+
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE, size=0.8, linetype="dotdash")+
  labs(x = "Year", 
       y = "Price")
```

This results in the following plot:
[image]

I want to include the `geom_smooth` trendlines separately in the legend so that there will be four items in the legend- x, y, trendline of x and trendline of y. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible way to get a custom legend for `geom_smooth`.

First, you need to add `linetype` as an argument of `aes` of `geom_smooth`. Then, you can customize it by using `scale_linetype_manual` to get two labels `x` and `y` and a different name in order to separate from `item` legend.

Using `guides`, you can modify this legend and add the same color pattern than the one used for `geom_point` and `geom_line`:

```r
ggplot(dat,  aes(x=year, y=price, group = item, color = item))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(shape= item))+
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype = item), method = "loess", se = FALSE, size=0.8)+
  labs(x = "Year", 
       y = "Price")+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dotdash","dotdash"), name = "trendline", labels = c("x", "y"))+
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c("dotdash", "dotdash"),color = scales::hue_pal()(2))))
```

[image]

Does it look what you are trying to get ?